# How do I get the (hh:mm) with the system time and target timezone as the inputs?

Tags: objective-c

For example, if the user's system clock is 10:00am (PST timezone).  How do I convert that to 13:00 (EST timezone) in Objective-C?

The end goal was to find a between time checker.

```
-(BOOL)isCurrentTimeBetweenStart:(NSString *)startTimeStr endTime:(NSString *)endTimeStr timezone:(NSString*)timezone{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatterEST = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatterEST setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    [formatterEST setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timezone]];
    NSString *currentTimeStr = [formatterEST stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];

    int startTimeMinutes   = [self minutesSinceMidnight:[formatter dateFromString:startTimeStr]];
    int endTimeMinutes  = [self minutesSinceMidnight:[formatter dateFromString:endTimeStr]];
    int currentTimeMinutes = [self minutesSinceMidnight:[formatter dateFromString:currentTimeStr]];

    if (startTimeMinutes <= currentTimeMinutes && currentTimeMinutes <= endTimeMinutes) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

-(NSDate *) toLocalTime : (NSDate *)date
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: date];
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: date];
}

-(int) minutesSinceMidnight:(NSDate *)date{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];
    return 60 * (int)[components hour] + (int)[components minute];
}
```

---

//sample call

```
if([self isCurrentTimeBetweenStart:@"03:40 PM" endTime:@"06:00 PM" timezone:@"America/New_York"]){
    NSLog(@"store is open!");
}else{
    NSLog(@"store not open");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) and set its `timeZone` property, like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:someDate];
```

Note that NSTimeZone does have a `+timeZoneWithAbbreviation:` method that accepts strings like “EST”, but the documentation itself advises against using it:

> In general, you are discouraged from using abbreviations except for unique instances such as “UTC” or “GMT”. Time Zone abbreviations are not standardized and so a given abbreviation may have multiple meanings—for example, “EST” refers to Eastern Time in both the United States and Australia.

You can get the list of available time zone names with `+knownTimeZoneNames` and, if necessary, allow the user to select the time zone they want to use from that list.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored internally referenced to GMT (UTC). On creating a date be default the users local timezone is used, the same on converting the data to a string representation.

If you want a string representation in another timezone use `NSDateFormatter` setting the timezone you want.